# User - deleted; question - remains; all reputation gained from it - remains; entry in the "recent reputation" - missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today I provided a correct answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452153/java-jaxb-generircs/2452452)

However, I just observed that my reputation for the day is 205, instead of the expected 230 (I have the greasemonky script for that). The question above doesn't appear in my daily reputation list (in the "recent" page). However I haven't (yet!) lost the reputation from it.

I assume this is due to the user being deleted, but should this happen, since his question remains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't lose any reputation. The question is there, and so is the answer, the upvote and the accepted answer. You shouldn't lose the reputation even after a recalc.

It does look like a bug though - the question doesn't appear on your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top), and clicking on the vote count shows **0/0** which is clearly wrong.

[alt text http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/5772/sobug.jpg](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/5772/sobug.jpg)

Comment: nice observation about the 0/0. yes, I _shouldn't_ but as a bug has already occurred, it might be transferred to the recalc. (Not that it would hurt that much to lose 25 rep :) )

Comment: +1 on the dynamite graphic

Answer (score 3):

Likely the user has been deleted for vote fraud and all of his votes have been canceled. This explains everything:

- The vote count is 0/0 because the vote has been canceled
- The normalized vote count is 1 because when the vote was canceled it wasn't updated; it will be updated when the cron script recalculates them.
- The question doesn't appear on your reputation page because the vote has been canceled
- Your reputation hasn't decreased because when the vote was canceled it wasn't updated; it will be updated when a rep recalc is done.

This is just an educated guess but I'm pretty sure this is what happened.

Comment: in that case, the vote-fraud mechanism should be changed, because my account isn't among the multi-accounts that were cross-voting themselves.